# Azure Function app isolated: issue routing

Tags: azure-functions

I have a function with route `/shops/{shopId}` and another function with route `/shops/location?loc=BE`.

When calling the second uri it goes into the first function and uses the value `location` for the shopId.

Even when the shopId is set to int, it tries to use this function but throws an error that it can't parse location to int.

The following works:

```
/shops/location/loc
```

But why can't we use the first version?

Answer (score 0):

> But why can't we use the first version?

because its location is treated as ShopId parameters in the first route. you can do this by adding one more route value and you can achieve this functionality.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace _72953528_RoutingAzureFunction
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Method1(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "shops/shopId/{shopId}")] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log, string shopId)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["shopId"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                ? "This HTTP triggered function1 executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }

        [FunctionName("Function2")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Method2(
           [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "shops/location")] HttpRequest req,
           ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["loc"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                ? "This HTTP triggered function2 executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {name} location. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

**Out put:-**
http://localhost:7015/api/shops/shopId/1
[image]

http://localhost:7015/api/shops/location?loc=delhi
[image]